# Apache HttpClient on Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient, htmlunit

For Apache HttpClient, when I authenticate to a webpage, do I need to set parameters for "hidden" input fields?

Also- Has anyone ever gotten HtmlUnit working on android?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're creating an HTML screen scraper. Setting aside all the inherent perils and ethical implications of such an undertaking, to be on the safe side, yes, you'd better include all the hidden fields. Preferably by scraping their values off the logon page. Scan the form, get the name/value pairs from all the fields (not just `hidden`), then fill username/password and do a POST.